# Topological space proof question

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $U$ be an open subset of a topological space $X$. Prove that $\overline{(\overline {(\overline U)^C})^C} = \overline U$.

The mathjax looks a little dodgy, so to clarify, the left hand side is:

the closure of the complement of the closure of the complement of the closure of U.

What would be the easiest way to approach this problem?

Comment: In odd situations like this when a modifier or bar takes up too much space, sometimes one writes the modifier as a superscript to the right of the object, so that one might write $(((\bar U{}^C)^\bar{})^C)^{\bar{}}$.

Comment: This question is equivalent to: prove that $\overline{\left(\overline{A^c}\right)^c} = A$ where $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

To handle problems like this use the important theorems
cl X\A = X - int A  (topological duality),
cl int cl int A = cl int A,
and for open U, int U = U.

(cl A = A^- = closure of A;  int A = A^o = interior of A)

Thus since U is open,
cl(X - cl(X - cl U)) = cl int cl U
= cl int cl int U = cl int U = cl U.
..

Answer (score 0):

For showing that $A=B$ most times it is convenient to show that $B\subset A$ and $A \subset B$.

Here is an example of a proof. I will replace $\overline{O}$ by $\mathfrak{cl}(O)$ for readability.

By elementary set theory you know that $\mathfrak{cl}( U)^C\cap U = \emptyset$(*). But since U is open we also have $\mathfrak{cl}(\mathfrak{cl}( U)^C ) \cap U = \emptyset$.
Thus 
$$ U \subset (\mathfrak{cl}(\mathfrak{cl}( U)^C ))^C $$
since  taking closures preserves this inclusions, we know that 
$$  \mathfrak{cl}(U) \subset  \mathfrak{cl}( (\mathfrak{cl}(\mathfrak{cl}( U)^C ))^C )$$
which is one half of what we want to prove.

For the other direction note that $ \mathfrak{cl}(O^C)^C \subset O$, for any set $O$(*). Taking $O= \mathfrak{cl}(U)$ and taking the closure on both sides gives the other inclusion.

(*) Here I used that $X \subset \mathfrak{cl}(X)$ for any set $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have trouble understanding the part "But since $U$ is open we also have... - 3rd line"

Comment: Why is it that since U is open we also have $\mathfrak{cl}(  \mathfrak{cl}( U^C)^C) \cap U = \emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry! Somehow I messed it up. Now it should be ok. The argument in the third line should be like this: if $A \cap B$ has empty intersection and $B$ is open, then the complement of $B$ is closed, so the closure of $A$ is contained the complement of $B$ and hence the complement of the closure of $A$ contains $B$. Taking $B= U$ and $A =\mathfrak{cl}(U)^C$ then gives the equation after the third paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ Cl(A)$ be the closure of $A.$ Let $Int (A)$ be the interior of $A.$

We have $Cl (Int (Cl (Int (A)))=Cl (Int A).$

Proof: $$ Cl(Int(A))=Cl(Int \;\;\;(Int (A)\;))\subset$$ $$\subset Cl (Int \;\;\;(Cl (Int (A))\;)\subset$$  $$\subset Cl(\;\;\;Cl (Int (A))\;)=$$ $$=Cl (Int (A)).$$

This a a well-known result.

Let $A^c$ be the complement of $A$ and let $A^-$ be the closure of $A.$

We have $Int(A)=A^{c-c}.$

Now if $U$ is open then we have $ U=Int(U)$ and therefore the LHS in your Q is  $$Cl( \;\; (U^-)^{c-c} \;\;) =Cl (Int (\;U^-\;))=$$ $$=Cl (Int (Cl (U)=Cl(Int(Cl(Int (U)=$$ $$=Cl(Int (U)=Cl(U).$$

Remark: There is a dual to $Cl(Int(Cl(Int(A)))=Cl(Int(A)),$ which is $Int(Cl(Int(Cl(A)))=Int(Cl(A)).$